# GPS problem on Samsung Android devices?

Tags: android, gps

I will like to know whether there is any problem getting location information in Samsung devices. The location fetching code works properly in all the devices except Samsung devices.

From whatever I have searched over the net it seems there is some problem with Samsung devices giving GPS fix. Is there any workaround for there? The application is working properly in Nexus one, HTC devices and Motorola Devices. But Samsung devices gives problem.

Can someone let me know of any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's much talk of GPS problems on Samsung Galaxy S phones (of which I have one). GPS lockon is slow or fails outright, sees fewer satellites than most any other GPS device in the same place/time, and has lower accuracy when a lock-on is established.

No one's come up with a reliable fix, as the problem's with the core Samsung code handling the interfaces with the GPS chip. There was an OTA patch released (JI6) for Galaxy S phones from some carriers that helped some people get better GPS performance, but most carriers never released it as the fix is also in the Froyo 2.2 update, which is currently slowly being released region by region.

Comment: I suffer from the same problem (Galaxy S 9000) and the Froyo update didn't provide any improvement.

Comment: I am developing application which has location fetching as the main feature. The complete feature of the app is based on Location information. So, isn't there any solution to this which can be done programmatically.

Comment: No, since you're just talking to the Androind location API. Unless you want to roll your own hardware level driver for every possible GPS chip in Samsung phones (can you even write hardware drivers for a Market app?), you can't do anything to fix it.

Comment: There is foursquare app on Samsung device and it makes use of GPS with no problems. Can someone tell how is foursquare managing to get the location fix without any problem?

Comment: There's more than just GPS for location. There's rough triangulation from cell towers, there's WiFi maps, etc... Foursquare could be using any/all of those. However, it won't be "fixing" Samsung's GPS problems - remember, it's a low level hardware/driver problem, not something patchable from within an Android app.

Comment: There are lot of forum discussions on this at samsung forums. But smartly these guys cant reproduce the problem, while the rest of the world can. They dont even share the code they tried with. Damn irritating. http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=233508&startId=zzzzz~

Comment: @sunil any solution ?"I am developing application which has location fetching as the main feature. The complete feature of the app is based on Location information. So, isn't there any solution to this which can be done programmatically. "